# How to update PostgreSQL database while using .NET 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I start to learn .NET 5 to create full-stack applications. I create a model with the following code:

```
public class Contact
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }

    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.PostalCode)]
    public int Zip { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string Emanil { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
    public string Phone { get; set; }

    // Seting up Date & Time
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    // Seting up using of image
    [NotMapped]
    [Display(Name = "Image")]
    [DataType(DataType.Upload)]
    public IFormFile ImageFile { get; set; }

    public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
    public string ImageType { get; set; }

    // Thinking about primary key that the database will manage
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // Let's think about a derive property (a combination of firstname & lastname)
    [NotMapped]
    public string FullName { get { return $"{FirstName} {LastName}"; } }
}
```

Unfortunately, after creating the app I saw a typo mistake in `Email` => `Emanil`.

Now after correcting the typo I try: `Add-Migration EmailUpdate` but it fails, I do try `Update-Database` as well still fail, I make corrections on each line were I have `Emanil` to `Email`:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("FirstName,LastName,Address1,Address2,City,State,Zip,Emanil,Phone,Created,ImageData,ImageType,ImageFile,Id")] Contact contact)
```

Just want to know the best way to update it (I use Visual Studio for the project).

Comment: What is the error message when you try Add-Migration ?

Comment: the migration just retur failed